# php code to get sum value and display max value from sum value

Tags: php, mysql

> table name--- voter
>
> field name voter
>
> type integer

I am selecting distinct values from this table, getting sum of voter field, and echoing this field in a loop.

I need to take the above summed value result in variable and display the *maximum* value from this sum field. How can I accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
<?php       
        $party = $rowco['partyname'];   
        $district = $rowco['district']; 
        $constituency = $rowco['constituency'];     
        $sqlvotes = "SELECT SUM(votes) AS vote,constituency FROM voter_count where state = '$state' AND partyname = '$party' AND district = '$district' AND constituency = '$constituency'";    
        $resultvotes = mysql_query($sqlvotes);  
        while($rowvotes = mysql_fetch_array($resultvotes,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {               
        ?>   
         <th><?php echo $rowvotes['vote']; ?></th>  
          <th><?php echo $rowvotes['constituency']; ?></th>       
    </tr>
    <?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that :

```
$max = -1;
while($rowvotes = mysql_fetch_array($resultvotes,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{               
    if ($rowvotes['vote'] > $max) $max = $rowvotes['vote'];
    ?>   
    <th><?php echo $rowvotes['vote']; ?></th>  
    <th><?php echo $rowvotes['constituency']; ?></th>       
    </tr>
    <?php 
} 

echo "Max value : $max";
?>
```

Comment: BJP 170 Nagpur-East
AAP 500 Nagpur-South
Congress 210 Akola-East
AAP 210 Akola-West
BJP 407 Akola-East
Congress 975 Nagpur-East  my table is displaying sum value like this now i want to find max value from above table and display max value...